# Any way to move "cells" in PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have multiple CSV files that need to be analyzed that have two identifying pieces of information in the top row. The next row below is blank. Third row contains headers. How to create 2 custom columns that contain "cells" 4 and 6 from the top row copied down to all of the more than 100 rows of data below? It is simple with Excel VBA but this data set is going to be used in perpetuity and later users may not be VBA literate. (Thanks for the table Alexis!!)

```
| Probe | 503     | SN:1256 | 8/27/2020 | 13:23 | AUG20  | BH02     |
|-------|---------|---------|-----------|-------|--------|----------|
|       |         |         |           |       |        |          |
| Tube# | Tube ID | MC #    | A B Cal   | Units | STD MC | Ratio    |
| 1     | 8       |  1      |           |       |        |          |
| 1     | 1       | -1      | Count     | 7403  | 1493   | 0.201675 |
| 2     | 1       | -1      | Count     | 7403  | 1486   | 0.200729 |
| 3     | 1       | -1      | Count     | 7403  | 1686   | 0.227746 |
| 4     | 1       | -1      | Count     | 7403  | 1705   | 0.230312 |
| 5     | 1       | -1      | Count     | 7403  | 1779   | 0.240308 |
| 6     | 1       | -1      | Count     | 7403  | 1954   | 0.263947 |
| 7     | 1       | -1      | Count     | 7403  | 1965   | 0.265433 |
```

Comment: Edit your post rather than trying to put a table in the comments.

Comment: I've attempted a table for you but it likely needs edits.

Answer (score 0):

Post sample data.

Something like this, assuming no column headers to start, would pull off the first row, and convert into columns for the remaining data

```
// get the first two columns of first row
TopRow1 = Table.First(#"PreviousStep")[Column1],
TopRow2 = Table.First(#"PreviousStep")[Column2],
// remove first row
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"PreviousStep",1),
// convert new first row to column headers
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
// custom columns to add the data we found above
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "TopRow1", each TopRow1),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "TopRow2", each TopRow2)
```